How to show different markup of a story, based on the viewport selected, in Storybook?
Now I have 2 Storybook setups:

one for desktop stories, which have a specific markup + CSS file
one for mobile stories, which have a different markup than the desktop one + a different CSS file

I want to merge those 2 Storybook setups under a single one. This is because I want to visualize the components stories in the same config, when changing the viewport (with the viewport plugin).
Any ideas?
Tried to find something returned/triggered by the viewport-plugin but couldn't find anything.
